# Responsive issue with secondary logo - not sticking in position

Tags: css, html, headers

I have modified the header.php file and CSS to get a second logo working on my page here: dev.dutil.com/optilink-testpage

It's the OptiLink logo on the right. 
 At full screen, I've gotten it about where it needs to be with this CSS:

```
.secondLogo { 
padding-top:15px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:-30px;
width:110px;
height:75px;
float:right;
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
right:12%;
z-index: 1000; 
}
```

However, with responsive design it's not working fully. When I collapse the window it will push really far in and then snap back to where the big hero image is but it's inconsistent. I tried to create a media screen rule as well but i'm having issues one way or the other.

Basically, the OptiLink logo on the right needs to stick to the edge of the container/hero image like the Dalton utilities logo, no matter the screen size.
Any tips on how to better achieve this?

Comment: This is not an answer on you question but i would set the z-index of you #nav-toggle higher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of bootstrap (which u use) this is fairly simple.

You can just do like this =

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="site-branding">logo 1</div>
<div class="secondLogo">logo 2</div>
</div>
</div>
*menu goes here*
```

first div you give :

```
.site-branding {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
width: 110px;
}
```

Second div :

```
.secondLogo {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried that CSS but no luck, it actually pushed the optilink logo into the hero image. Also, I have the sitebranding set to float:none so that it remains on top of the nav menu, and floating left causes it to alight when responsive with this CSS

Comment: please note that i'm adding a div with the class "row" around the 2 div's and that i have the menu under that. I'm more then happy to help you with some live coding and checking as i need the points to set a bounty on a question of my own

Comment: I know for sure that this setup should work since i love coded this onto your website and checked all responsive modes (as you can see in the pictures)

Comment: Ok that would be fine, but how are you suggesting to add the row class? Since it's wordpress, I had to add the second logo image through HTML in the header.php file

Comment: Well thats a whole other question. Are you building your own theme? Do you have a child theme?. When you create a header.php you can define whatever you want wherever you want. Can you provide the code of you header.php?

Comment: No, this is just a simple modification on the one press theme they are currently using. They wanted this added before tomorrow on top of the existing site, just taking it off the menu and making it a logo instead

Comment: Please give me the code of your header.php files so i can take a look at it and provide you back the good code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57589/discussion-between-swat-be-and-h-norman).